# Insert/Alter/Update scripts not responding in MySql

Tags: mysql

There is a strange problem that I am facing currently.
The MySQL db that I was using since at least last seven months has stopped responding to `Create/Update/Alter` scripts. (The same scripts were working before.) The MySQL DB is however responding to `Select` statements.
I am not getting any logs (apart from connection timeout) :- they simply say that connection timed out (only in case of `create/update/alter`. the same works fine for `select` statements)

1) I have tried running the scripts using a Java App as well as MySQL Workbench. The behaviour is same (Connection timeout in Java App, and MySql Hangs and gives options to force quit)

2) I have tried restarting the MySQL Server so as to remove any locks

What can be the possible causes for such a behaviour?

Regarding logs: since the behaviour is happening through MySQL workbench also, Java Logs are not applicable here

Regarding Code: Since same queries were working before, and are working on another instance of similar DB, they are fine.

Below is  a screenshot for User's Grant. I am using root with all privileges.
[image: User Grant Access]

Comment: Correct. By updating db I mean running scripts that involves modification. i.e. running update/create/alter scripts.

Comment: Does your user have the GRANT access set for all these? Check the user persmissions.

Comment: Does the server write logs at all? Harddisk full?

Comment: @ACV I think yes, the user has access. (I am not very well versed, but I think yes : attached screenshot)

Comment: @stef77
MySql instance is installed on my local machine. I checked just now, It has around 60 GB of free space.

Comment: Just tried a work around which somehow is working fine.
I took db dumps from existing DB recreated another DB from the dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what caused the issue, but here is the work around that helped me:

1. Since SELECT queries were working, I took the DB dumps from the MySql DB
2. Dropped the DB from MySql
3. Recreated the DB from dumps generated in step 1.